# In ansible how to read file content src and added it to a dest file only if the content is not present in dest?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

In ansible how to read file content source file and added it to a destination file only if the content is not present in the destination file?

Looking to do the below in a more ansible way!

```
shell: cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys >> /home/foo/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the *authorized_keys* for alice and bob at test_11

```
root@test_11:/ # cat /home/alice/.ssh/authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbX user@host1
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbY user@host2
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbZ user@host3
```

```
root@test_11:/ # cat /home/bob/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbZ user@host3
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbU user@host4
```

<sup>(The module *ansible.posix.authorized_key* does not test the consistency of the keys.)</sup>

Read alice's *authorized_keys*

```yaml
    - command: cat /home/alice/.ssh/authorized_keys
      register: out
```

gives

```yaml
out.stdout: |-
  ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbX user@host1
  ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbY user@host2
  ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbZ user@host3
```

Add the keys to bob's *authorized_keys*

```yaml
    - authorized_key:
        user: bob
        key: "{{ out.stdout }}"
```

Run the play in *--diff* mode. The output shows the module works as expected

```yaml
TASK [authorized_key] **********************************************
--- before: /home/bob/.ssh/authorized_keys
+++ after: /home/bob/.ssh/authorized_keys
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@
 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbZ user@host3
 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbU user@host4
+ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbX user@host1
+ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbY user@host2
```

gives

```yaml
root@test_11:/ # cat /home/bob/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbZ user@host3
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbU user@host4
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbX user@host1
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzFbY user@host2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: test_11
  tasks:
    - command: cat /home/alice/.ssh/authorized_keys
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
    - authorized_key:
        user: bob
        key: "{{ out.stdout }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [authorized_keys](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html) module:

You need to do something like in the example:

```yaml
- name: Set authorized key in alternate location
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: username
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

You need to change user to the proper user and the key for the file where you've the key.